# Error 403 forbidden ao consumir webservice CEP

Tags: java, json, web-service, spring, spring-mvc

Estou tentando consumir um webservice de ceps mas sempre me retorna 403 e ele é publico.

**Teste do WebService Funcionando :**

http://apps.widenet.com.br/busca-cep/api/cep.json?code=01001000

**Meu Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/busca-cep")
public class BuscaCEPController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BuscaCEPController.class);

    @Autowired
    private LogService logService;

    @Autowired
    private BuscaCEPService buscaCEPService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<CEPResult> buscaCEP(String code) {
        try {
            logService.info(LOG, "action=buscaCEPIniciado, cep={}", code);
            CEPResult result = buscaCEPService.buscarCEP(code); 
            logService.info(LOG, "action=buscaCEPConcluido, cep={}", code);
            return new ResponseEntity<CEPResult>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logService.error(LOG, "action=buscaCEPErro, cep={}, e={}", code, e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<CEPResult>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

}
```

**Meu Serviço de consumo**

```
  @Service
    public class BuscaCEPService {

        public CEPResult buscarCEP(String code) {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            CEPResult result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://apps.widenet.com.br/busca-cep/api/cep.json?code=" + code, CEPResult.class);
            return result;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Para que a pergunta possa ser tratada dentro do escopo deste site é importante você [edit] e fornecer um [mcve] do problema que não dependa de nenhuma API externa (por exemplo, simulando dados já baixados de forma que não seja necessário ninguém da comunidade consultar links, e que a pergunta continue válida se a API mudar). Caso seja um problema de entendimento/funcionamento da API e não do algoritmo ou do funcionamento da sua parte do código, já seria o caso de consultar o suporte do fornecedor da API diretamente. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testei chamadas para este exemplo de URL fornecido:

```
http://apps.widenet.com.br/busca-cep/api/cep.json?code=01001000
```

O que percebi e que causa o **403** é que o servidor precisa que o cabeçaho `User-Agent` esteja presente na requisição, independente do conteúdo do cabeçalho, podendo ser vazio.

Então o que precisamos fazer é colocar este cabeçalho para que a requisição feita vá com ele.

Com o `getForObject` do `RestTemplate` não há como informar cabeçalhos, uma alternativa é executar o `exchange` passando uma `HttpEntity` com os cabeçalhos necessários.

Um exemplo demonstrado esta abordagem seria assim:

```
private static final String URL = "http://apps.widenet.com.br/busca-cep/api/cep.json?code={code}";

public String findCEPByCode(final String code) {
    final RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "");

    final HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    final ResponseEntity<String> result = template.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class, code);

    return result.getBody();
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new CEPService().findCEPByCode("01001000"));
}
```

Que irá gerar este JSON (em unicode por que não forcei nada para UTF-8):

```js
{
   "status":1,
   "code":"01001-000",
   "state":"SP",
   "city":"S\u00e3o Paulo",
   "district":"S\u00e9",
   "address":"Pra\u00e7a da S\u00e9 - lado \u00edmpar"
}
```

Para retornar o seu `CEPResponse`, basta alterar o tipo, ficando assim:

```
public CEPResponse findCEPByCode(final String code) {
    final RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    // dependendo das configurações do contexto do spring não precisará disto
    template.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "");

    final HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    final ResponseEntity<CEPResponse> result = template.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, CEPResponse.class, code);

    return result.getBody();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado , funcionou perfeitamente !

Comment: só por curiosidade como você descobriu que precisaria passar o cabeçalho user-agent?

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto como é GET, então testei pelo browser primeiro. Como o browser sempre coloca esse cabeçalho (e outros), daí inferi que era ausência de algum cabeçalho (deve ser configuração do servidor do WS), então testei e bingo :)

Comment: Entendi, valeu pelo retorno